# eCommerce : Product configurator under Hybris platform

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have to implement product configurator in hybris platform that allowing users customization front office interface (product details).
Like changing color of product, size, make text and managing prices.

I'm looking actually for open source product desinger.

Anyone has an experience with any integrated framework or any other recommendations ?

Kind regards,
Soufiane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using SAP CPQ which is integrated with Hybris out of the box, you can have a look at [openCPQ](http://webxcerpt.github.io/openCPQ/index.html)

Comment: Hi Benoit, i allow myself to give you some examples for our desire final products configurator : http://www.21diamonds.de/Online/Goldringe/Isobel/Swarovski-blazing-red/Wei%C3%9Fgold-585.html?ringSize=126

Answer (score 0):

Managing the sizes, prices etc of products is performed via the productcockpit. Changes you make here will be reflected in the Accelerator storefront. This is also extensible and customisable.